# Laravel - variable from form not being saved in create method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to save the information from a form, into the database. I can successfully save all fields minus one - a select field.

**Form HTML (blade):**

```
{!! Form::select('ClinicTypes', $clinicTypes, null, ['class' => 'form-control',
       'name' => 'speciality']) !!}
```

That displays in HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" name="speciality">
    <option value="1"></option>
    <option value="2"></option>
</select>
```

If I: `dd($request->get('speciality'));` it returns '1', which is correct, however, when I add this into the `create` function, it saves in the database as 0.

**Snippet from create method:**

```
'clinic_types_id' => $request->get('speciality'),
```

[image: dd screenshot]

**Snippet from database:**

[image: database]

**Schema:**

```
Schema::create('clinics', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->integer('clinic_types_id');
```

Why is it saving as 0, instead of 1? Any help would be hugely appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Can you share your table schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might make sure it's in the `$fillable` array for the model.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Clinic extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['clinic_types_id'];
}
```

Comment: Perfect, such an easy thing to overlook! Thank you!